# Import data from one excel file to another user prompted

Tags: vba, excel, import-from-excel

How do I import data from one excel file to another by using a prompt method. Having the user select the path file, or typing in the excel workbook name. Current code with no success. Please advise.

```
' Get customer workbook...
Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the customer workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)

' assume range is A1 - C10 in sheet1
' copy data from customer to target workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

targetSheet.Range("A1", "C10").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1", "C10").Value

' Close customer workbook
customerWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a public function that uses the filedialog to allow the user to browse and select the file you want to manipulate in your code. The return value will be the filepath of the chosen file. It is currently set to only allow a single selection `.AllowMultiSelect = False`.

```
Public Function GetFilePath(strTitle) As String

    Dim fso     As Object
    Dim varFile As Variant
    Dim strPath As String

    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    Set fso = Application.FileDialog(3)
    With fso
        .Title = strTitle
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
    End With

    For Each varFile In fso.SelectedItems
        strPath = varFile
    Next

    Set fso = Nothing

    GetFilePath = strPath

    Exit Function

PROC_ERR:

    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & "; " & Err.Description
    GetFilePath = "Null"

End Function
```

So instead of:

```
' get the customer workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)
Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
```

Use:

```
Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(GetFilePath("Select the customer file"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give the user a prompt to browse and select the workbook they want to import.  It will import data from the worksheet (in this case Sheet1) in the selected workbook and import into a worksheet in your current workbook (that has the same name Sheet1). It will copy the range you set (in this example A1:Z100) and paste it starting with A1 in your current workbook.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File ()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFileName(Title: "Browse for your file & import", 
Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Openbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z100").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     OpenBook.Close False

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```